# Getting "High Score" table from score table

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got the following sql table setup for tracking the scores of different players.

```
create table scoreTable (
  userName varchar2(100),
  score number
)
/
insert into scoreTable values ('Andy', 200);
insert into scoreTable values ('Andy', 33);
insert into scoreTable values ('Bob', 444);
insert into scoreTable values ('Charlie', 213);
insert into scoreTable values ('Charlie', 4);
insert into scoreTable values ('Charlie', 777);
```

Now I want to return each player's highest score using a select statement. I'd like the result to be

```
NAME      SCORE
_____     ____
Andy      200
Bob       444
Charlie   777
```

I'd prefer to just have one select statement that gives the top result for any number of distinct name values. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is such a thing possible?*

**Yes.**

Simple aggregation:

```
SELECT userName, MAX(score) AS score
FROM scoreTable
GROUP BY userName
ORDER BY userName;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/XGIRJ19200)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

Return entire row using `RANK` function:

```
WITH cte AS
(
     SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY userName ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn
     FROM scoreTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY userName;
```

or using `SELF JOIN`:

```
SELECT s1.*
FROM scoreTable s1
LEFT JOIN scoreTable s2
  ON s1.userName = s2.userName
 AND s1.score < s2.score
WHERE s2.userName IS NULL
ORDER BY userName;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/CGB24733)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess I may have simplified the problem a little too much. Is there any way to return the entire row? For example, say I have a date column so the player can see when they got that score.